# The right approach to overlay data on the picture?

Tags: php, imagick

There is a [class](https://github.com/wnull/userbars-warface-generator/blob/master/src/Draw.php) for rendering data on the userbar.

It works fine, but I want to clarify. In the process, the data is superimposed on the image, and you should use `clone` for both `Imagick` and `ImagickDraw` - to save the previous overlays.

```
private function createImage($file): Imagick
{
    $this->Imagick = new Imagick(__DIR__.'/Draw/Images/'.$file);
    return $this->Imagick;
}
```

An example of how `clone` is used:

```
private function drawRank(): Imagick
{
    $image = clone $this->Imagick;
    $rank = $this->createImage(self::RANK_IMAGE);
    $rank->cropImage(32, 32, 0, $this->vector[$this->interface->rank_id]);
    $image->compositeImage($rank, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 64, 18);
    return $image;
}
```

In the end it turns out like this:

```
private function call()
{
    $this->Imagick = $this->createImage(self::BACKGROUND_IMAGE[$this->l]);
    $this->Imagick = $this->drawRank();
    $this->Imagick = $this->drawingProfile();

    header('Content-Type: image/'.$this->Imagick->getImageFormat());
    echo $this->Imagick;
}
```

How correct is this? I have doubts about this approach. Is this normal practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bad logic :

```
      A=1  
      A=2  
      A=3  
      here A=3, value 1 and 2 are lost !
```

try this way

```
$im1 = $this->createImage(self::BACKGROUND_IMAGE[$this->l]);
$im2 = $this->drawRank();
$im3 = $this->drawingProfile();
```

then compose final image with compositeImage

```
   // assuming transparent color is used in im2 and im3 
   // compose with image 2
   $im1->compositeImage ($im2, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT,0,0, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
   // compose with image 3
   $im1->compositeImage ($im3, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT,0,0, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
```

Comment: It turns out, without `clone` still can not do?

Comment: @LetsSay hmm ... actually, with my method, do not use a clone! but for the mention in the question: "is this a normal practice?" . As far as logic goes, I do not think so. It's better to separate the logic: creating a function to build each image, then using them to compose the final image is easier to maintain.